# My system time resets to January 2007. How can I solve this?

Tags: hardware, time

I am facing a weird problem that my system clocks resets to jan 1 2007 to 0:00. Can anybody help me to rectify it?

The bios show the same time. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should try changing your motherboard's battery.
It's a possible cause.

Comment: Can't think of something else at this point.

Answer (score 4):

When your computer is switched off, the time is usually kept ticking over by a battery-powered system,which normally operates independently of the OS.There might be a problem with your machine's **BIOS settings** or its **CMOS battery**.

**NOTE:**
You can also test the battery with a multimeter.You should get right around 3.3v.Most **BIOS** have a **Vbat sensor**.Anything under 3.0v means the battery is dying.Better to take the battery out and replace it with a new one.

Comment: how can i check it is a problem with bios i have also reseted it to default now..

Comment: After resetting the bios settings did you set the time in your BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

you should change cmos battery

Answer (score 1):

check the cmos battery i have had the same problem with older computers